# class within a class in php

Tags: php, class, object

Here is the problem outline:

```
    /*First object*/
    class MYCLASS {

              /*Some Properties and methods*/

              public function foo() {
                     $this->somevar = 'yes';
                     $this->display = '<tag>' . $this->somevar . '</tag>';

                     /*NOTICE this line, not using return, but echo*/
                     echo $this->display;
              }
    }

    /*Second object, instantiating first object inside*/
    class NEXTCLASS {

              /*Some Properties and methods*/

              public function yoo() {
                     $this->maa = new MYCLASS;
                     return '123' . $this->maa->foo() . '456';
              }
    }

    /*Show output*/
    $next = new NEXTCLASS;
    echo $next->yoo();
```

This should output `123<tag>yes</tag>456` but it is showing `<tag>yes</tag>123456`

I think `$this->maa->foo()`is an *object* and that's why it is printed before *strings*. Got 2 relevant links: [stack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468616/call-a-class-inside-another-class-in-php), [`__toString()` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring).

**Question is:** Without changing `MYCLASS` can I alter `$this->maa->foo()` inside `NEXTCLASS` in any way, that output will be in right order?

Comment: You can use the `ob_XXX` functions to capture the output.

Comment: you're doing output in `MYCLASS`. that output will be executed BEFORE the concatenation in `NEXTCLASS` ever gets a chance to execute.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar Now I get the difference between just programming and computer science. I learned only the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an output-buffer.

```
public function yoo() {
    ob_start();
    $this->maa = new MYCLASS;
    $this->maa->foo();
    $buffer = ob_get_flush();
    ob_end_clean();
    return '123' . $buffer . '456';
}
```

https://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this:

```
/*NOTICE this line, not using return, but echo*/
echo $this->display;
```

Your comment actually has the answer. Use `return`:

```
return $this->display;
```

And your output will be:

```
123<tag>yes</tag>456
```

If you echo immediately, you will first print that tag and THEN the rest of the string. Alternatively, you can try output buffering if you're really against the idea of using return here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute

```
return '123' . $this->maa->foo() . '456`;
```

it first has to call `$this->maa->foo()`. Inside that method, it echoes `<tag>yes</tag>`. Then it returns `NULL` (because there's no `return` statement). `yoo` then concatenates that, so it executes

```
return '123' . NULL . '456';
```

which returns the string `123456`.

Finally, the caller of `$next->yoo()` echoes that string.

Yuo could do the following in `yoo()`:

```
public function yoo() {
    ob_flush();
    ob_start();
    $this->maa = new MYCLASS;
    $this->maa->foo();
    $temp = ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
    return '123' . $temp . '456';
}
```